# C++ input is not blocking properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, input, console-application

I'm writing voice communicator. I have to control program from console, because we decided not to develop GUI - it's not important and it takes time. So, there is a thread which handles user commands from console:

```
void* ClientApp::commandHandler(void)
{
    std::string input;
    std::string connPort;
    std::string connAddr;
    std::map<std::string, int> mapStringValues;
    mapStringValues["connect to server"] = 1;
    mapStringValues["connect to host"] = 2;
    mapStringValues["disconnect from server"] = 3;
    mapStringValues["start call"] = 4;
    mapStringValues["end call"] = 5;
    mapStringValues["set TCP port"] = 6;
    mapStringValues["help"] = 7;
    mapStringValues["exit"] = 8;

    std::cout << "Write command" << std::endl;
    //int i = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        //std::cout<< ++i<<std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        switch(mapStringValues[input])
        {
            case 1:  //connect to server
                std::cout << "TODO: connect to server" << std::endl;
                break;

            case 2:  //connect to host
                std::cout << "IP:" << std::endl;
                std::getline(std::cin, connAddr);
                std::cout << "port:" << std::endl;
                std::getline(std::cin, connPort);
                connectToHost(connAddr, std::stoi(connPort));
                break;

            case 3:  //disconnect from server
                std::cout << "TODO: disconnect from server" << std::endl;
                break;

            case 4:  //call
                if(callInProgres == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
                networkController->udpConnect();
                startCallViaNet();
                break;

            case 5:  //end call
                endCallViaNet();
                break;
            case 6: 
                break;
            case 7:
                showCommands();
                break;
            case 8:
                audioPlayer->stopThread();
                audioRecorder->stopThread();
                networkController->stopSendUDPThread();
                networkController->stopRecvUDPThread();
                networkController->stopRecvTCPThread();
                networkController->shutdownUdpConnection();
                networkController->shutdownTcpConnection();
                exit(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem appears when I have to accept incoming call. I need the input so I can write yes or no. Thread which handles internet connection calls function which asks and gets answer (y/n). Next actions depend on what acceptCall function returned. I know it can cause trouble - many threads asking for input. So to prevent it, before thread calls this function, it terminates commandHandler thread(it's pthread and I cancel it - maybe not elegant, but works fine), gets input and then start again commandHandler:

```
int ClientApp::acceptCall(std::string ip)
{
    std::cout << "Start call from "<<ip<<"? (y/n)" << std::endl;
    char c = (char)getchar();  /* std::cin, getline, scanf... - I tied it*/
    if(c == 'y'){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And then something strange happens when I reject call and it starts commandHandler again. First getline from commandHandler is not waitng for input anymore. Loop starts working and no input is possible. I was trying all combinations of std::cin.ignore() and std::cin.clear(), all possible input functions. The best what I succeeded was blocking getline after another commandHandler start, but my commands didn't match any case in switch - commands were proper, but nothing, except one loop cycle happend after input. I'm going mad with this. I read hundreds of threads about C++ input but nothing helps me.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And also show us some actual input that causes the behavior?

Comment: It's a lot of code to perform this situation and I don't have acces to my computer till 6 pm :/

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, when you get the input with `getchar` you end the input with a newline? Then the `getchar` reads and extracts the character you enter from the buffer, but leaves the newline for the next input operation to read.

If there's input that should be ignored, then the standard C++ way is to call a stream function call just that, [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore). Please follow the link, it show an example on how to use it.

Comment: Like I wrote in comment in second function - I tried getline, etc. There is no difference what I use and I was trying also use ignore without parameter, with size and '\n', with max size of buffer, etc.

Comment: @Franek The only way for `std::getline` to return immediately is if there's either a complete line in the input buffer, *or* if there's some error state set on the stream. Have you checked for any of that?

Comment: Should I, before it enters the loop, check if there is error state? And then do what? Lets assume, that in entire program getline is the only way for input. Could you write some example code?

Comment: @Franek You should probably do it as part of the `std::getline` call, like e.g. `if (!std::getline(...)) { /* something's wrong */ }`

Comment: I found some trace. Do you think there could be some corelation between BSD sockets accept function and standard input? I am calling acceptCall afert accept function so I could accept or reject connection. When it calls getline after accep, it takes something from cin(its not empty) and sets all error flags to 1.